# I need my code to run on a range of cells then loop back infinitely

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a ping monitoring tool thats almost perfect. The only thing I need to change now is to have it run from row 2 to row 207 then loop back to row 2 and repeat ad infinitum. My coding skills are weak and my google-fu hasn't led me to an answer that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below:

```
Sub PingSystem()
Dim strip As String
Do Until Sheet1.Range("E215").Value = "STOP"
Sheet1.Range("E215").Value = "TESTING"
For introw = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        strip = ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Value
    If Ping(strip) = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Value = "Online"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Font.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Font.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Value = "Offline"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    If Sheet1.Range("E215").Value = "STOP" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Loop
Sheet1.Range("E215").Value = "IDLE"
End Sub
```

I tried changing "65536" to 207 but that just broke the entire thing. I've tried wrapping the code in another For loop. Nothing I've done has worked.

Comment: Try:

`For introw = 2 To 207`

Comment: Using ActiveSheet in your code is unreliable: your code will behave differently depending on ... well ... what is the active sheet.

Comment: Is there code line to change cell `E215` in `Sub Ping()`? If not, the nested loops are infinite loops. `Sheet1.Range("E215").Value = "TESTING"` change the cell `E215` before `For` loop. No code change the cell again in `For` loop. The value of cell `E215` is `TESTING` after `For` loop. Then `Loop` clause will start next round loop ( row 2 to row 207 ). ...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub PingSystems()
    Dim strip As String, rw As Long, wsData As Worksheet, res As Boolean
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Systems") 'for example
    
    StatusCell.Value = "TESTING"
    
    Do
        For rw = 2 To wsData.Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).row
            DoEvents 'allow changes in cStatus
            If StatusCell.Value = "STOP" Then GoTo done
            With wsData.rows(rw).Cells(4)
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
                .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                .Value = "Pinging..."
                DoEvents
                res = Ping(wsData.rows(rw).Cells(3).Value)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(res, 0, 6)
                .Font.Color = IIf(res, RGB(0, 200, 0), RGB(200, 0, 0))
                .Value = IIf(res, "Online", "Offline")
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            End With
        Next rw
    Loop

done:
    StatusCell.Value = "IDLE"
End Sub

Sub StopPing()
    StatusCell.Value = "STOP"
End Sub

Function StatusCell() As Range
    Set StatusCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Systems").Range("E2") 'for example
End Function

Function Ping(v) As Boolean
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Ping = Rnd() > 0.1 'dummy test
End Function
```